# Update column based on another column's value which is also being updated

Tags: sql-server

I wish to update column A with null. And I also wish to update column B with null, but only if it's value matched the original value of column A.

```
Update MyTable
Set A=Null,
    B=Case When B=A Then Null Else B End
```

Will the above statement work? Is the value of A within the Case statement already Null when evaluated? And does the order of the updates matter?

Any way to write this better and avoid setting B=B when it's not really required? I need to do this within 1 statement as the actual query is long and complex involving many joins and sub-queries.

Comment: There is no way to avoid assigning _some_ value to `B` in your query, so this is something you will have to accept unless you want to use dynamic SQL.  As @sagi mentioned, just assign `B` before nulling `A` and your query should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You query should be fine if you just place B before A like this becuase the order does matter. It is possible that it will also work like you wrote it, but I doubt it.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET B = CASE WHEN A = B then null else B END,
    A = NULL
```

Comment: I thought about this as well. But I need to be sure about this before I implement. Is it possible that the SQL compiler might change the order if it finds it more efficient?

Comment: If you write the query with B first, everything will be fine. You know you can also test it, and then roll back... @navigator

Comment: Just swallow the blue pill and everything will be fine.  The DBA will handle any such unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the columns being updated does **not** matter: in fact, you will also get the original value of *A* (that is, the one you would get from the *deleted* virtual table if you were writing a trigger), despite of the value you are assigning to it during the update.

You can easily test this with this script, which contains two UPDATEs with a different order of the updated columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    X INT,
    Y INT
)

INSERT Test (Id, X, Y)
VALUES (1, 2, 3)
INSERT Test (Id, X, Y)
VALUES (4, 5, 6)

UPDATE Test
SET X = X + 1,
    Y = X
WHERE Id = 1

UPDATE Test
SET Y = X,
    X = X + 1
WHERE Id = 4

SELECT *
FROM Test
```

Here the *SELECT* would return this:

```
Id  X   Y
1   3   2
4   6   5
```

As you can see, the updated value of *Y* is always the same of the original *X*, despite the different order of the UPDATEs.